# python twitter api 1.1 get retweet id

Tags: python, api, twitter, compiler-errors, tweets

I need to print the ids of users that have re-tweeted a tweet. when I run my code, this is what I get. what am I doing wrong?

reqs()

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    reqs()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\twitter_travel_guard.py", line 136, in reqs
    retweets = t.statuses.retweets_of_me(since_id=str(tweet['id']), max_id=str(tweet['id']))
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\twitter\api.py", line 204, in **call**
    return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data, _timeout)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\twitter\api.py", line 235, in _handle_response
    raise TwitterHTTPError(e, uri, self.format, arg_data)
TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 429 for URL: 1.1/statuses/retweets_of_me.json using parameters: (max_id=345206977242210304&oauth_consumer_key=...&oauth_nonce=...&oauth_signature_method=...&oauth_timestamp=1371498240&oauth_token=...&oauth_version=1.0&since_id=345206977242210304&oauth_signature=m...)
details: {"errors":[{"message":"Rate limit exceeded","code":88}]}

code:

```
def reqs():
    t = Twitter(auth=OAuth('....'))
    tweets = t.statuses.user_timeline.TravelGuard()
    for tweet in tweets:
        retweets = t.statuses.retweets_of_me(since_id=str(tweet['id']), max_id=str(tweet['id']))
        print retweets
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use 
    retweeters

instead. boom figured it out myself

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which library you're using, but I'd say this part:

```
since_id=str(tweet['id']), max_id=str(tweet['id'])
```

is part of the problem: you're giving the since and max ids the same value so there can't be anything between those restrictions. I think you want to look for retweets of each tweet, so wouldn't you just pass the id of `t` into the function (not sure what the parameter is named)?

Comment: I found this function instead https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids

how would I implement this into python?

Comment: What library are you using to make the `Twitter(auth=OAuth('....'))` line work? Does it have some documentation?